# FlowPlayer, JWPlayer and HLS streaming

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, flowplayer

I have a server (nginx-rtmp-module) that streams 2 in 2 formats: HLS and RTMP.

```
HLS: http://streamr.ru:8080/hls2/track1.m3u8
RTMP: rtmp://streamr.ru/video/track
```

I try to play them both with FlowPlayer and JWPlayer Premium. There is no problem with RTMP. But HLS doesn't play in HTML 5 mode (in Safari, iPad or iPhone). I guess something is wrong with encoding, but what?

Thanks.

That's my ffmpeg config:

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 4 -rtbufsize 512000k -channels 2 -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format
uyvy422 -framerate 25 -f dshow -i video=" Decklink Video Capture (2)“: audio=" Decklink
Audio Capture (2)» -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -r 25 -b: v 750k -s 1280x720 -acodec 
libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -b: a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv «rtmp://streamr.ru/video2/track1»
```

Comment: Your example files do not exist.  Please can you advise what you are using to create the m3u8 chunks

Answer (score 1):

http://streamr.ru:8080/hls2/track1.m3u8 brings me to this page:

404 Not Found
nginx/1.1.19